# Controller vibration with Monogame

Tags: monogame

Is there a simple way to make a connected Xbox controller vibrate with Monogame? I know that GamePad.SetVibration is not implemented but it seems like this would be a common enough problem that there would be an easy answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use SharpDx and its [XInput implementation](http://sharpdx.org/documentation/api/m-sharpdx-xinput-controller-setvibration) to set the vibration on the controller, but I'm not entirely sure how well this would work in practice.